# Validate XSD Schema with ISO-8859-1

Tags: java, xml, validation, iso-8859-1

I have a XML. And this XML i have to validate with e XSD. And the XSD requested a ISO-8859-1 encoding.

I have try with this Code but it is not working. See someone the fault?

```
    public boolean validateXML(Document doc) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException {

    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
    String xml = xmlOutput.outputString(doc);

    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(true);
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        final SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

        factory.setValidating(true);
        final Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream(SCHEMA_PATH)));
        factory.setSchema(schema);

        factory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource(xml);
        is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

        builder.parse(is);
        return true;
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        throw pce;
    } catch (IOException io) {
        throw io;
    } catch (SAXException se) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the top from XSD

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>
```

Comment: The encoding in the XML declaration of the XSD has no relevance for the encoding of the XML files which use the XSD. They may be use any encoding as long as it is specified or the default (UTF-8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as the below way :

```
    public class XMLUtils {

  private XMLUtils() {}

  // validate SAX and external XSD 
  public static boolean validateWithExtXSDUsingSAX(String xml, String xsd) 
  throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException 
  {
    try {
      SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
      factory.setValidating(false); 
      factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

      SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
      SAXParser parser = null;
      try {
         factory.setSchema(schemaFactory.newSchema(new Source[] {new StreamSource( xsd )}));
         parser = factory.newSAXParser();
      }
      catch (SAXException se) {
        System.out.println("SCHEMA : " + se.getMessage());  // problem in the XSD itself
        return false;
      }

      XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
      reader.setErrorHandler(
          new ErrorHandler() {
            public void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
              System.out.println("WARNING: " + e.getMessage()); // do nothing
            }

            public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
              System.out.println("ERROR : " + e.getMessage());
              throw e;
            }

            public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
              System.out.println("FATAL : " + e.getMessage());
              throw e;
            }
          }
          );
      reader.parse(new InputSource(xml));
      return true;
    }    
    catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
      throw pce;
    } 
    catch (IOException io) {
      throw io;
    }
    catch (SAXException se){
      return false;
  }
}

public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception{ 
    System.out.println
        (XMLUtils.validateWithExtXSDUsingSAX
            ("c:/temp/YourXML.xml", "c:/temp/YourXSD.xsd"));

  }
}
```

> output :(if it is validated)   true

I hope it would help you..

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. But now i have this error                            '2016-06-15 11:26:13,952 ERROR: Not Validate XML 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This parser does not support specification "null" version "null"'

Comment: can u share your xsd in above?

Comment: what jdk version u r using?

Comment: The XSD is too long. It is >5000 Lines. But the first Line from the XSD is <?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>. I use JDK 1.60_45. Is a old project. But i now have see that my problem is the the "XMLOutputter" A Moment, i will writ another answer

Comment: ok no problem , just download xerces jar from this link [xerces](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxercesjar.htm) and install it in your workspace lib. I hope this would solve your incompatible version issue.. no matter what jdk u use... Actually xerces is recommended parser while we validate..

Comment: Is it not possible to solve this problem without this jar? because i'm not allowed to install jar's or something

Comment: I am not sure about the other possible way, but by this jar that problem would get resolved....

Answer (score 0):

I have the Metohd validateXML. And i set the Outputter to "setEncoding("ISO-8859-1")"

Buy why is at the end the XML File staring with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Methode validateXML

```
private void validateXML(Document doc) throws Exception {

    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat().setEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));

    String docStr = xmlOutput.outputString(doc);

    //InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(docStr.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));
    byte[] bytes = docStr.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

    Source xml = new StreamSource(inputStream);
    File xsdfile = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(SCHEMA_PATH).getFile());

    SchemaFactory schemaFactor = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = schemaFactor.newSchema(xsdfile);


    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

    validator.validate(xml);

}
```